# Xcode-How i can add other language on localization window

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm trying to create a localization file for strings. I added a file named Localizable.strings in project. But localization window does not appear in other languages.I can only choose some languages. What do I need to be able to select other languages. (Ex: Turkish,Polish...)

[image]

Comment: Yes i did . Other languages do not appear on this screen. I could not find the option to add. Now from this list, I can only select those languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a lot of languages in project properties. Look at the picture. Hope this help.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Wonderful answer. I was investigating the cause appear in two days.